# Convert array object to value of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, postgresql

I have an `array` of objects structured like this:

```
[{ a: '1', b : '2'}, {a : '3', b : '4'}]
```

For the purpose of preparing data for insertion into database, I need a string of object values like this:

```
('1', '2'),('3', '4')
```

With the same ordering of values.. apart from the naive way of iterating through each object in array and constructing a string, is there a better much easier way of doing this?

Comment: How about the join method?

Comment: `join` on what keys?

Comment: If your string values are more than just simple digits, you'd want to rely on query formatting methods that are available within the database framework that you are using. Otherwise, you are risking to create invalid strings when they have special symbols in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following

```js
var arr = [{ a: '1', b : '2'}, {a : '3', b : '4'}];
    
var result = arr.map(function(item){
    return "('" + item.a + "', '" +  item.b + "')";    
});
    
console.log(result);
console.log(result.join());
```

Answer (score 2):

For on line lovers.

```
var arr = [{ a: '1', b : '2'}, {a : '3', b : '4'}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(result, item, i){
    return result + "('" + item.a + "', '" +  item.b + "')" + i===arr.length-1?'': ',';    
}, '');
```